# What type of interactions occur when CH4 dissolves in CCl4

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

When ionic compounds dissolve in polar solvents many types of factors come into play determining their solubility. Some of them may be: ion- dipole interactions, lattice energy, high dielectric constant of the solvent etc.

But I was unable to understand what kind of interactions take place between non-polar solvent and non-polar solute. I was reading about the solubility of $\ce{CH4}$ in $\ce{CCl4}$ and since they were both covalently bonded I couldn't explain the interactions. Any references would help too.

So my question is:

**What type of interactions occur when $\ce{CH4}$ dissolves in $\ce{CCl4}$**

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems weird you know about things like lattice energy or ion-dipole int. but not about [vdW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force), new to organic chemistry?

Comment: @Mithoron oh yes.Totally. Thanks for the lead.Should I delete this question?

Comment: I think it can stay as duplicate.